# Error 401 Unauthorized - Spring RestTemplate OAuth2.0

Tags: java, spring, rest, oauth-2.0, spring-boot

I am calling a service that is secured by OAuth2.0. I am using RestTemplate and making the call asynchronously using callables. When I fire a single request , I get successful response. However when I fire multiple requests in parallel , the service is intermittently returning 401 error. Please can you help in identifying the cause of this error?

Comment: You should post some code and there is a better option than `RestTemplate`: [OAuth2RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html)

Comment: Thanks ksokol , it is a large project , I am trying to isolate the piece that is causing the issue. In my project , we expose a rest service. Our client passes the authorization header. We propagate that to our client , hence we aren't using OAuth2RestTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

If you start the VM with -Djavax.net.debug=all you will be able to see the response from the server.

This error is not helpful and is provided by Spring OAuth2 for a number of conditions (including bad client_secret)